# Is GHC's auto-derived `Eq` instance really *O(N)*?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I just noticed while trying to learn to read GHC Core, that the
automatically derived `Eq` instance for enum-style data types such as

```
data EType = ETypeA | ETypeB | ETypeC | ETypeD
           | ETypeE | ETypeF | ETypeG | ETypeH
           deriving (Eq)
```

seems to be transformed into a *O(N)*-like lookup when looking at GHC's core representation:

```
$fEqEType_$c== =
  \ (a_ahZ :: EType) (b_ai0 :: EType) ->
    case a_ahZ of _ {
      ETypeA ->
        case b_ai0 of _ {
          ETypeA -> True;
          ETypeB -> False;
          ETypeC -> False;
          ETypeD -> False;
          ETypeE -> False;
          ETypeF -> False;
          ETypeG -> False;
          ETypeH -> False
        };
      ETypeB -> case b_ai0 of _ {__DEFAULT -> False; ETypeB -> True};
      ETypeC -> case b_ai0 of _ {__DEFAULT -> False; ETypeC -> True};
      ETypeD -> case b_ai0 of _ {__DEFAULT -> False; ETypeD -> True};
      ETypeE -> case b_ai0 of _ {__DEFAULT -> False; ETypeE -> True};
      ETypeF -> case b_ai0 of _ {__DEFAULT -> False; ETypeF -> True};
      ETypeG -> case b_ai0 of _ {__DEFAULT -> False; ETypeG -> True};
      ETypeH -> case b_ai0 of _ {__DEFAULT -> False; ETypeH -> True}
    }
```

Am I misinterpreting the GHC core output? Shouldn't algebraic data types provide an integer id for each constructor, which could then be compared directly in *O(1)*? Also, why does the first case clause for `ETypeA` not make use of `__DEFAULT` as the other clauses do?

**update:**

As per suggestion by Simon Marlow, I addad a 9th constructor `ETypeI`, and then GHC switched to using `dataToOtag#`:

```
$fEqEType_$c/= =
  \ (a_ahS :: EType) (b_ahT :: EType) ->
    case dataToTag# @ EType a_ahS of a#_ahQ {
      __DEFAULT ->
        case dataToTag# @ EType b_ahT of b#_ahR {
          __DEFAULT ->
            case ==# a#_ahQ b#_ahR of _ {
              False -> True; True -> False
            }
        }
    }
```

For me, this adds the question as to what the trade-offs  between GHC core's `case` and use of `dataToTag#` are, and why this particular cut-off of 9 constructors for using `dataToTag#` is implemented in GHC.

Comment: This can be reproduced with GHC version 7.0.3 and 7.1.20110529

Comment: In fairness, there's little difference between *O(1)* and *O(n)* when *n* is small. What are the constant factors involved? Is it a tradeoff between time and space?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Equality comparison of `EType` is O(1) because the `case` construct is O(1).

There might or might not be an integer tag for constructors.  There are several low level representation choices, so the Core generated works for all of them.  That said, you can always make an integer tag for constructors, and that's how I usually implement the derived comparison when I write Haskell compilers.

I have no idea why `ETypeA` gets a different treatment.  Looks like bug.

Comment: I looked at the generated assembler code, and the `case`-construct seems to be emitted as indirect jump via an address-vector; what I didn't understand though is why the index used for addressing the vector isn't compared directly

Comment: @hvr It's not compared directly because people have not complained loudly enough about it yet. :)  I think it should be, but it doesn't change the asymptotic complexity of comparison.  And not just for equality, but `Ord` as well.