# Haskell GHC: what is the time complexity of a pattern match with N constructors?

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, pattern-matching, complexity-theory

Let's say we have the following Haskell:

```
data T = T0 | T1 | T2 | ... | TN

toInt :: T -> Int
toInt t = case t of
  T0 -> 0
  T1 -> 1
  T2 -> 2
  ...
  TN -> N
```

What algorithm is used to perform the pattern match here?  I see two options:

(1) Linear search, something like

```
if      (t.tag == T0) { ... }
else if (t.tag == T1) { ... }
else ...
```

(2) Binary search, which would be sensible in this specific task: searching for `t.tag` in the set {`TO`...`T1023`}.  However, where pattern matching in general has many other capabilities and generalizations, this may not be used.

Compiling with GHC, what algorithm is used, and what is the time complexity in terms of N, for pattern matching on `t` in `toInt`?

Comment: This question reminded me of [Is GHC's auto-derived `Eq` instance really *O(N)*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212387)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A jump table is used, making the pattern-match a constant time operation.

Unfortunately I'm unable to find an up-to-date citation for this, although [this page](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/CmmType) mentions the implementation of Cmm-level `switch` statements as jump tables, and [this old tagging design document](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/SemiTagging) uses a `case` on a `Bool` as an example, producing a jump table.

Comment: This means that the time complexity is **O(1)** and also **Θ(1)** in case it wasn't clear.

Comment: Hey, No fair! I wanted the `O(1)` to subsume the actual `Θ(0)`.

Comment: You could cite the [GHC source](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/codeGen/CgUtils.hs#L647).