# Haskell Pattern Matching: Readability and Performance

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm going through the [learn you a haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion#hello-recursion) tutorial and
I've been tripping over some of the examples the author 
has given.

For example he reimplemented zip as follows:

```
zip' :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]  
zip' _ [] = []  
zip' [] _ = []  
zip' (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x,y):zip' xs ys
```

He uses a similar approach for all his other examples,
where he puts the most specific patterns first. Here is a slightly different
version of the zip function:

```
zip' :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
zip' (x:xs) (y:ys)  = (x, y):zip' xs ys
zip' _ _            = []
```

As far as I understand both methods do the same thing. If
an empty list is provided either way (x:xs) or (y:ys)
won't match which will finish the recursion by appending
the empty list [].

1. I personally prefer the second version for readability, but maybe I'm wrong in doing so.
2. Does it have any effect on the performance of a method? As far as I understand if the top most pattern does not match, Haskell will check against the next pattern. Does the order of the patterns affect performance?

Kind regards,

**Edit:**

Possibly duplicate of:
[Haskell GHC: what is the time complexity of a pattern match with N constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027384/haskell-ghc-what-is-the-time-complexity-of-a-pattern-match-with-n-constructors)

Summary: The order of the patterns is very important for the semantics (in terms of strict evaluation of the arguments) and the readability of a function. The pattern match itself will always be in **O(1)** time complexity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell GHC: what is the time complexity of a pattern match with N constructors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027384/haskell-ghc-what-is-the-time-complexity-of-a-pattern-match-with-n-constructors)

Answer (score 7):

> As far as I understand both methods do the same thing.

almost; with an exception:

```
\> zip' undefined []   -- 1st definition of zip'
[]
\> zip' (filter (< 4) [1..]) [1, 2, 3]
[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]
```

whereas:

```
\> zip' undefined []   -- 2nd definition of zip'
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
\> zip' (filter (< 4) [1..]) [1, 2, 3]
[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)   -- gets stuck here; never returns
```

in other words, the 2nd definition always forces [weak head normal form](https://wiki.haskell.org/Weak_head_normal_form) for *both* arguments.

Performance-wise, this means that one can construct a *pathological* example  such that WHNF involves heavy computations, therefore one definition performs very differently than the other.

Comment: That is true. But `zip' undefined [1, 2, 3]` will produce an exception in both cases. So I can't see how this helps or rather why it would be desirable.

Comment: @Nimi, in this case it only determines *which* argument is unconditionally strict.

Comment: @Nimi the point was that you can make the two functions behave very differently and not do the same thing. note the other example, `zip' (filter (< 4) [1..]) [1, 2, 3]` to see how this can also impact performance.

Comment: @behzad.nouri Ahh.. I can see it now. Thx